# autohotkey script to collapse expand in onenote 2016

Tags: autohotkey, onenote

i'm trying to expand and collapse the paragraphs in onenote 2016. the key combo to expand in it is shift+alt+pluskey[+] [not numpad one] and to collapse , it is alt+shift+minuskey [-] [not numpad one]

I tried to bind left win key to expand and tilde key to collapse

I tried this

```
LWin::
Send, {shift}{alt}{+}
Sleep, 100
return
```

but it's not working. i am totally new to autohotkey. and also trying to combine both scripts [expand and collapse] in one script and to make this script only work when onenote window is active.

update : from the answers , it finally worked for me.

```
LWin::
SendInput, +!{+}
return

`::
SendInput, +!{-}
return
```

Comment: Good that you got it to work. Also, you don't need brackets around `-` since that character doesn't have a special meaning in send commands. The brackets are only used to *escape* characters that have special meanings in send commands. Full list is found on the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending and then releasing each of the keys.
You want them all to be held down.
For that you could use `SendInput, {Shift Down}{Alt Down}{+}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}`, or to make it easier, you can just use the special keys the [send commands](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) recognize as modifiers: `SendInput, +!{+}`.

Also, assuming the sleep command you have there isn't important for whatever reason, you can use the [remapping syntax](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs//misc/Remap.htm#Remap) instead of a send command to end up with a sweet clean little one liner like this:  `LWin::+!+`
And yes, you indeed don't put brackets around the second `+` in this case, as weird as it may seem.

Comment: Ok I see you pointed out your own oddity, too...  I selected my versions for the answer as they help make the answer portable to other multi-modifier key mappings, but of course, the uniqueness of ahk _is_ its clever (intuitive?) syntax for using modifiers in the shorthand forms you showed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the "`+`" key IS the `=` key shifted, you don't need to add the "`Shift`" and this works:

```
LWin::
    Send, {alt down}{+}{alt up}
return
```

Or alternatively,

```
LWin::
    Send, {alt down}{shift down}{+}{shift up}{alt up}
return
```

and

```
LWin::
    Send, {alt down}{shift down}{=}{shift up}{alt up}
return
```

both work (all the above on a Std US Keyboard where the "+" key is the same as "=" key shifted).

Hth,

Comment: Depends on the current keyboard layout, and on the method used to send input. And sounds like OP is not on a keyboard layout where the `+` key comes from shifting a `=` key. If that would've been the case, `Send, !{+}`, or what you used, would've worked, yes.

Comment: Well, nothing to stop OP from doing it expressly (as I show in my edited answer) and oddly "shift and +" and "shift and =" (on std keyboard where they are on the same key but the + is shifted and = is not) both work the same!